# limit of error with integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Let $g: [0,1] \to R$ is continuous real function. Then $$\lim_{n\to \infty }n\sum_{i=0} ^{n-1}\left(\int _{\frac i n} ^{\frac {i+1} n}\left(g(x)-g\left(\frac i n\right)\right)dx\right)$$ exist?

I can if $~g'~$ is continuous. It has counterexamples?

Comment: What does "error" have to do with this? And which terms are included in the integral? Just $g(x)$ or both?

Comment: I forget sum....

Comment: The sum is

$\int_0^1 g(x)dx - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} g(i/n)$.